# Movie about an apocalypse and five people

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this comedy (?) movie on T.V. no more than 5 years ago. Here's all I remember.

- The movie's protagonist was a guy, who left his college dorm and took to the roads after some apocalyptic event.
- This person has set some "rules" for himself, and has written down all of them in a book, I think.
- He thinks he is the last human alive, but later on meets four other people.
- There was one man, who was hell-bent on finding and eating the last of some kind of yellow candy. (If I remember right, it was called a Winkie.)
- The other two were girls, a twenty-something and a 12-year-old.
- I cannot recall the fourth person.
- I think it was the fourth person who led the gang into the house of some super-famous actor.
- From there onwards, the movie continues.
- I can faintly remember that the movie ended in a park with a Ferris wheel.

I know this is a bit vague; a list of possibles will have to do.

Comment: Was it set in London ? It resembles [28 Days Later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/28_Days_Later) but need more details to confirm.

Comment: No, no, i remember it was a comedy movie; I'll add that to the question.

Comment: The super-famous actor was Bill Murray

Comment: @LamarLatrell yep.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's [Zombieland](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1156398/):

> A shy student trying to reach his family in Ohio, a gun-toting tough
>   guy trying to find the last Twinkie, and a pair of sisters trying to
>   get to an amusement park join forces to travel across a zombie-filled
>   America.